# how to subtract the value using checkbox from database

Tags: php, mysqli

Well I want to subtract the value in database and just try any method but it still fail.I don't know if the codes in query in below is working. Please explain it to me fluently because I'm hard to understanding the logic of codes. I really appreciate and I'll try to do my best Thank you!

**borrow.php**

```
    <form method="post" action="borrow_save.php">
```

Due Date
                    
                    
                    
                
                 
                    

                                 Borrow

```
            <div class="span8">
                    <div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Select Book</strong></div>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="example">

                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>Acc No.</th>                                 
                                    <th>Book title</th>                                 
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                    <th>Author</th>
                                    <th>Publisher name</th>
                                    <th>status</th>
                                    <th>Add</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                              <?php  $user_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select * from book where status != 'Archive' ")or die(mysqli_error());
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)){
                                $id=$row['book_id'];  

                                $copy=$row['book_copies'];


                                $cn=count($id);
                                for($i=0; $i < $cn; $i++)

                                        if($copy > 0){ ?>
                                            <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">


                                <td><?php echo $row['book_id']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row ['catalog']; ?> </td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?> </td> 
                                 <td><?php echo $row['publisher_name']; ?></td>
                                  <td width=""><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td> 
                                <?php include('toolttip_edit_delete.php'); ?>
                                <td width="20">
                                            <input id="" class="uniform_on" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

                                </td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php   }
                                ?>

                                <?php  }  ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

            </form>

<script>        



$(".uniform_on").change(function(){
var max= 3;
if( $(".uniform_on:checked").length == max ){

    $(".uniform_on").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             alert('3 Books are allowed per borrow');
    $(".uniform_on:checked").removeAttr('disabled');

}else{

     $(".uniform_on").removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

**borrow_save.php**

```
<?php


    $id=$_POST['selector'];
$member_id  = $_POST['member_id'];
$due_date  = $_POST['due_date'];

if ($id == '' ){ 
header("location: borrow.php");

}else{




mysqli_query($dbcon,"insert into borrow (member_id,date_borrow,due_date) values ('$member_id',NOW(),'$due_date')")or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
$borrow_id = $row['borrow_id'];
$borrow_id=$dbcon->insert_id; 
mysqli_query($dbcon,"UPDATE book SET book_copies = book_copies - 1 where book_id='$book_id'");  <!- this is the query that I don't know if it's work -->


$N = count($id);

for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{


mysqli_query($dbcon,"insert borrowdetails (book_id,borrow_id,borrow_status) values('$id[$i]','$borrow_id','pending')")or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
}

}  
?>
```

Comment: You are passing `$book_id` as a string into the query, where book_id is an integer. Have you debugged all of the rest of the code to ensure your inputs are valid when being passed into the query too? Also you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) when inserting data (especially for client input)

Comment: Where did you define $book_id in your subtraction query?

Comment: Sorry I will use prepared statements when this code is already functioning so I will know how to prevent in sql injection, and I don't know what to do adding a + 1 value in database is easy but subtracting so difficulty just don't know what to do sorry

Comment: @AliSheikhpour in table book

Comment: You didnt set value of $book_id in borrow_save.php file at all.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour how can i set a value although I update in Book table

Comment: as I see you get the id of books using '$id=$_POST['selector'];'. Perhaps this is not a single ID and you may get 3 comma separated IDs as you have three choices. So you have to split the value of $id into single IDs and update each book separately.You can print the value of '$_POST['selector']' and see you are not  getting a single ID!

Comment: @AliSheikhpour ok I will Try that thank you my friend!

Comment: @AliSheikhpour https://imgur.com/a/QrlxU it's getting the value my friend just didn't subtracting the books in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already inserting in `borrowdetails` on a per `book_id` basis within your `for`-loop, so the easiest solution would be to move that update statement to that loop too:

```
for($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbcon,"UPDATE book SET book_copies = book_copies - 1 where book_id=?") or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id[$i]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));

    // Your insert-query (still NEEDS protection against SQL-injection!!!)
    mysqli_query($dbcon,"insert borrowdetails (book_id,borrow_id,borrow_status) values('$id[$i]','$borrow_id','pending')")or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
}
```

Comment: Hi! sorry for my late reply, Yes it subtract but when I borrow one book it subtract 2 books in database , btw thanks for your reply I really appreciate I'm happy to seeing the books subtracting from your code :D

Comment: and when I return it the books returned by 2 books how can I change it into 1 borrow only not 2 books thank you my friend!

Comment: "it subtract 2 books in database": you either have 2 items in your array (would also insert two rows in `borrowdetails`) or you're updating the `book`-table somewhere else in your code too -- I don't understand your second question :S

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience my friend there's a variable in my books.php  $count = mysqli_num_rows($borrow_details); $total =  $book_copies  -  $count; and I erase this everything so the code you give to me is working now, Thank you!!! and sorry for my bad english